# oracle synchronize 2 tables

Tags: oracle, triggers, view

I have the following scenario and need to solve it in ORACLE:

Table A is on a DB-server
Table B is on a different server

Table A will be populated with data.
Whenever something is inserted to Table A, i want to copy it to Table B.
Table B nearly has similar columns, but sometimes I just want to get 
the content from 2 columns from tableA and concatenate it and save it to 
Table B.

I am not very familiar with ORACLE, but after researching on GOOGLE
some say that you can do it with TRIGGERS or VIEWS, how would you do it?

So in general, there is a table which will be populated and its content 
should be copien to a different table.

This is the solution I came up so far

```
create public database link
  other_db
connect to
  user
identified by
  pw
using 'tns-entry';

CREATE TRIGGER modify_remote_my_table 
  AFTER INSERT ON my_table 
  BEGIN INSERT INTO ....?
  END; 
/
```

How can I select the latest row that was inserted?

Comment: You should also tell us if you want this synchronization to happen immediately or it can be deferred. If you want an immediate sync. then you must use a trigger or create a materialized view over Table B and make it refresh on commit (that's a bit tricky, but MUCH better than triggers). If it can happen some time after the insert on Table A, then this could be a dbms_job or any other scheduled process, which could happen during a non-production load on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the databases of these two tables are in two different servers, then you will need a database link (db-link) to be created in Table A schema so that it can access(read/write) the Table B data using  db-link.

**Step 1:** Create a database link in Table A server db pointing to Table B     server DB

**Step 2:** Create a trigger for Table A, which helps in inserting data to the   table B using database link.  You can customize ( concatenate the values) inside the trigger before inserting it into table B.

This link should help you

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-create-a-database-link-in-Oracle

Comment: Yes, You can use AFTER INSERT Trigger, which will help you for all Inserts happening to your trigger defined table.  The table B won't be synchronized for UPDATES and DELETES of Table A.

Comment: Well if I want that, then I need to create multiple TRIGGERS for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and so on right?

Comment: Nope.  You can create one trigger  alone which will be like "AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON"

Comment: Updated Edits. Please check

Comment: @DeeJay14 - I'm sorry, but I would never suggest a trigger to tackle any problem, besides really some kind of a last resort. First of all, the trigger obfuscates the logic and adds complexity to the process. Second - you can get it so complex at some point (or forget about it) and you'll wonder where those regressions come from. Third - in 99.9% of the cases there's another more straightforward way of doing it ...

Comment: @g00dy It really depends on the scenario .  Triggers and materialised views are the approach to synchronise the tables.  You can't really say "Never" to triggers as they server for specific purposes and the user scenario here certainly needs one....

Comment: In this case triggers are the wrong choice. We talk about triggers wich send data to a different database. Yes, you can do this in theory but in practical environments this simply does not work well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with triggers. But there may be a few disadvantages.

- What if database B is not available? -> Exception handling in you trigger.
- What if database B was not available for 2h? You inserted data into database A which is now missing in database B. -> Do crazy things with temporarily inserting it into a cache table in database A.
- Performance. Well, the performance for inserting a lot of data will be ugly. Each time you insert data, Oracle will start the PL/SQL engine to insert the data into the remote database.

Maybe you could think about using MViews (Materialized Views) to replicate the data via database link. Later you can build your queries so that they access tables from database B and add the required data from database A by joining the MViews.

You can also use fast refresh to replicate the data (almost) realtime.

From perspective of an Oracle Database Admin this would make a lot more sense than the trigger approach.

Comment: Beat me to it.  As soon as I read the question, an mview just seems to make a ton more sense then performing table synchronization using triggers.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

database links are considered rather insecure and oracle own options are having licences associated these days, some of the other options are deprecated as well.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3051239ba401e416565cdd912e0de8c

uses ora_rowscn to sync tables across two different oracle databases.